# EventsThreadsShutdown not always, ProcessExit always works, why

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, process-exit

I need a general purpose (any `C#` app) way of catching the event of any type of `C#` application ending so I can write log data to a file at that time.

I discovered that `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.EventsThreadShutdown` does not catch the `shutdown` event for a Multithreaded C# application I am testing with called `SrcChess2`.   `EventThreadShutdown` does work with simple single threaded applications.

I then discovered that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` does seem to work correctly with Multithreaded and single threaded apps.

Can anyone explain why `EventsThreadsShutdown` does not always work, does not work with my Multithread Application?

Thanks!

Comment: Somebody has to subscribe a SystemEvents event before that event will ever fire.  Don't use it.